# Como forçar o evento "change" de um input select, mesmo sem escolher outro valor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

São dois problemas:

1 - Ao carregar um input select tentei utilizar um trigger para forçar o "change", mas não surtiu efeito.

2 - Tenho 2 selects. Quando mudo de fato o valor do primeiro, o evento change é chamado e "esconde" valores do outro select, porém se o valor que foi escondido é o atual selecionado ele não some do combo, somente da lista.

Como fazer funcionar o change inicial e como fazer sumir da maneira correta os itens que tentei esconder?

Segue o código no fiddle para constatacao dos erros: http://jsfiddle.net/T52EE/

JS:

```
$("#cb").trigger("change");
$("#cb").on("change", function(){
    var cb1val = $(this).val();
    $("#cb2 option").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() <= cb1val){
             $(this).hide();   
        }
        else{
            $(this).show();
        }            
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="cb">
    <option value="0">Valor 1</option>
    <option value="1">Valor 2</option>
    <option value="2">Valor 3</option>
    <option value="3">Valor 4</option>
    <option value="4">Valor 5</option>
</select>

<select id="cb2">
    <option value="0">Valor 1</option>
    <option value="1">Valor 2</option>
    <option value="2">Valor 3</option>
    <option value="3">Valor 4</option>
    <option value="4">Valor 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: O segundo problema está um pouco confuso.

Comment: Eu atualizei o fiddle. Quando seleciono o "Valor 1" no primeiro select o "Valor 1" deve ser ocultado do segundo select. Porém ele continua aparecendo, só some da lista. Pelo menos no chrome.

Comment: Pronto editei a [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16746/5082)

Comment: O primeiro problema era que a forçada no change deveria ser apos a funcao change. E ele verificou isso. E o segundo problema eu expliquei no comentario da sua resposta e me baseei no dele para fazer da maneira que eu esperava. De qualquer forma muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apenas simula a alteração da seguinte forma:

```
$("selector").change();
```

Mude o JS para:

```
$("#cb").change(function(){
    var cb1val = $(this).val();
    $("#cb2 option").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() <= cb1val){
             $(this).hide();   
        }
        else{
            $(this).show();
        }            
    });
    //Resposta pergunta 2
    $("#cb2 option[value="+cb1val+"]").attr("selected","selected");
});
$("#cb").change();
```

Comment: Testei no meu fiddle e não surtiu efeito também.

Comment: Realmente o $("#cb").change(); tem que estar depois da funcao change. Obrigado.

Comment: E sobre o problema numero 2 você conseguiria me ajudar?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo respondi [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16746/5082)

Comment: $("#cb2 option[value="+cb1val+"]").attr("selected","selected"); adicionei essa linha na minha resposta isso irá resolver seu problema.

Comment: Eu fiz um pouco diferente, mas valeu a ideia.     cb1val++;$("#cb2 option[value="+cb1val+"]").prop("selected",true);

Answer (score 1):

Com javascript puro você pode usar o `onchange()`

```
document.getElementById("cb").onchange();
```

O segundo problema se resolve assim:

```
$(this).show().attr('selected',true); // assim você seleciona o item que pode ser exibido
```

Comment: Valeu andorinha, ate tentei mas essa ultima linha selecionava o ultimo registro do select e nao o proximo. O resultado que eu gostaria esta no meu fiddle atualizado.